# EWS: Searching by address in SentItems

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is there a way to **search by address** of the recipient into **SentItems folder** using SearchFilterCollection ? 
I can get results only by using "**DisplayTo**", which works fine adding the name of the recipient.
I know there are more options **(AQS)**, but i have to use this kind of search because i need to include an **ExtentedProperty**.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something [similar to this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633645(v=exchg.80).aspx), extending it with the extended property you were talking about:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.Default);

SearchFilter searchFilter = 
  new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Sender, "example@domain.com");

FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = 
  service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, filter, view);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tholle, but i want search in SentItems for destination address .  The property should be ToRecipents ... and it seems not working .... i am struggling to find a solution